# Application for master's course: should my motivation letter include my contact?

Tags: masters, germany, motivation

I am applying for a master's program at a german university, and as my whole application includes a CV (with my detailed personal info and contact), should my motivation letter include my contact at the begining? Or is the fact that i am submitting my CV enough for them?
Also, do I include the contact of the university as well?

Comment: The word "contact" is a bit ambiguous here. Do you in all cases just mean information about how to contact you (contact information) or another person who you use as an intermediary (a contact)?

Comment: @Buffy, i mean when you write ur name, e-mail, tel number, address.. at the top left corner

Comment: @Buffy, would you know if I should include the contact of the university as a whole, or of the specific department that I'll be applying for? (currently, i only added the name of the uni, and its adress)

Comment: I'm confused again. My answer assumes you mean information about how they can contact you. That would be your own email, etc. with nothing about their university or department.

Comment: @Buffy, hahaa im sorry for being so confusing. what i meant by the university's contact is: its name, its address, ..
Or maybe should I add the infos of the specific department (name of uni, address of department (each departmet has its own adress) and maybe phone number and email of department)

Comment: I think for the heading of a formal letter, the university and department are probably enough, unless you are addressing it to a specific individual. Then their name and title should be included.

Comment: @Buffy, no email no telephone number, right?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably make it easy to find your contact information by anyone reviewing your application. It is probable, but not necessary, that they will have your complete package, but if they can find the information easily, they will be more likely to contact you rather than delaying it.

So, a certain amount of repetition is called for, I think.